# Flex - Java byte to mp3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, lame

I've a problem in converting byte to .mp3 sound file. In my case I do it using FileOutputStream using its write(bytes) method but it just creates a data file with mp3 extension but I cannot play it in any player on my PC.

Note: I'm recording it from Flex Michrophone and send ByteArray to java.

Which libraries should I use to add mp3 sound file headers etc. in java?

UPDATE: I couldn't even convert my raw data to Wave format that is supported by java sound api.. It creates for me sound with recorded sound but with a noise - where's the problem?

Here's my code for wave:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 2, 44100, true);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, bytes.length/format.getFrameSize());


AudioSystem.write(stream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(path+"zzz.wav"));
```

What's wrong with my AudioFormat??? And which one do I have to use in MP3 case ?!

Urgent help! Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just writing the raw bytes to a file with the name extension .mp3 doesn't magically convert the data to the MP3 format. You need to use an encoder to compress it.

A quick google search found [LAMEOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/) which is a Java API for the popular [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) MP3 encoder.

Comment: Mm actually what I need is a lib that doesn't use system libraries - cause I do development in Mac os and the program I'm working on have to work on windows and linux?! this kind of lib that uses system libraries will waste my time on testing..

Comment: Recently I've found lamejb library thats a wrapper of Lame - so doen't need any Lame libraries from system. But there's not any example anywhere and the ones in examples folder under downloaded zip are just test classes from which I couldn't understand so much