# Convert MP3 to PCM in Java

Tags: java, mp3, media-queries, javasound, pcm

I want to convert MP3 file to PCM in Java.

How to do that?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried, what is the problem and what is the question.

Comment: @MikkoP I am searching for any Java library/API which will convert mp3 to PCM...

Comment: This question where the OP tries the exact opposite might be interesting (as soon as there is a solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424659/flex-java-byte-to-mp3/12424832#12424832

Comment: Try this http://java2everyone.blogspot.in/2011/01/create-java-mp3-to-wav-converter.html

Comment: @Philipp There has been a J2SE+JMF solution to this specific requirement since Java 1.3.

Comment: @Sri Maybe you should add JavaZoom as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Get the [`mp3plugin.jar`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) of the JMF.
- Add it to the run-time class-path of the app. to provide a decoder SPI for MP3.
- Get an [`AudioInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) for the MP3 from the [`AudioSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) of Java Sound.
- Convert it to PCM using [`getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat,AudioInputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat-javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream-).

Comment: Sorry for the necropost but, how do I know the mp3plugin.jar is added to the run-time class-path? I have it under referenced libraries, should that be enough?

I ask because this solution isn't working for my mp3 file.

Comment: @PerryMonschau *"how do I know the mp3plugin.jar is added to the run-time class-path?"* A good sign the MP3 Service Provider Interface is on the class path is that the app. can read an MP3 (just like it can read a WAV ot any other sound file type Java supports without it).